# Способы создания браузера в режиме headless Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Всем добрый день. Я использую undetected_chromedriver и с ним режим headless не работает (браузер не создается и выдается ошибку).
Какие есть еще способы создания браузера selenium в режиме без головы?

Comment: Так, может, лучше сперва попробовать разобраться в причине появления ошибки и устранить её?

Comment: Эту ошибку не могут решить на гите библиотеки undetected_chromedriver. Рабочего способа нет. Скорей всего несовместимость с новыми версиями хрома